# Polynomials modulo other polynomials, understanding polynomial division

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to understand quotient rings:

When we take $\Bbb R[x]/ \langle x^2+1 \rangle$ we have elements$$f(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle \in \Bbb R[x] / \langle x^2+1\rangle\text{ for } f(x)\in \Bbb R[x]$$

So this apparently means by the division algorithm that any polynomial in $\Bbb R[x]$ will be reduced mod $x^2+1$ to be a linear polynomial. I tried to verify this but perhaps I have become confused:

$$2x^2+3x+2 \pmod {x^2+1}$$

$$\frac{2x^2+3x+2}{x^2+1}=2+\frac{3x}{x^2+1}$$

Does this mean I have $3x \pmod{x^2+1}$?

Comment: Yes. It means $3x$ is an element of the coset $2x^2+3x+2+\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: For any real polynomials p and q with deg(q)>1 we have  p=q.r+s where r,s are (some) real polynomials with deg(s)<deg(q).So p is congruent to s (mod q).

Answer (score 0):

In $A=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ you consider polynomial of  form $ f (x) + (x^2+1)$. In particular 2 polynomials $ f, g\in \mathbb{R}[x] $ are equal in $A$ if and only if $x^2-1$ divide $ f (x)-g (x)$ , in this case you write $(x^2+1)+ f (x)= (x^2+1)+ g (x) $. For example, the polynomials $x$ and $1$ are not equivalent in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, after performing your division, you may write $$ 2x^2+3x+2=2\times(x^2+1)+3x$$ Hence taking modulus $(x^2+1)$, you will have $ 2x^2+3x+2 = 3x\pmod {x^2+1}$.